# What defines a group that you need to press VO + shift + down to enter on macOS voiceover?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

Basically I noticed if you have stuff inside an anchor tag:
i.e.

```
<a href="asdfasfd">
   <div aria-label="inner div">
   </div>
</a>
```

When voiceover is on the anchor, you cannot reach the div inside by doing VO + right or right arrow keys, you must enter using VO + shift + down to enter the "group". However, this behavior is not the same with a div/span.

```
<div role="group" aria-label="outer div">
   <div aria-label="inner div">
   </div>
</div>
```

In the previous block, voiceover will find the group, and pressing VO + right will find the inner div, rather than skipping over it like in the anchor tag. Similarily VO+shift+down will also do the same. My question is, for accessibility purposes what makes something only enterable via VO+shift+down, and is there some kind of documentation that talks about this kind of stuff because I can't find any. I know that there is a lot of configuration you can do within voiceover which allows you to change the functionality of some of these keys. I'm also using polymer if that changes any accessibility behavior based on built in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

a `<div>` is not inherently accessible. That is why it does not get exposed when you press VO + right (Move to next *focusable / interactive* item) when within the `<a>`.

This is the same behaviour with nearly any other element.

When you press `VO + shift + down` you are asking the screen reader to interact with the element (i.e. access information within a focusable item).

### why does it work with a div role="group" then?

When you apply a `role="group"` you are indicating to the browser that you want to add a collection of controls to the accessibility tree.

Technically the behaviour should be the same *but* screen readers have to try and work around this because a lot of mistakes are made by developers. (this is my best guess as to why it happens, it could be coded to simply follow a rule that `role="group"` should always expose its children)

So in the above scenario you signal 'hey this is a group of controls' and the screen reader then expects a set of controls (normally `<buttons>`).

Because there are some `<divs>` with `aria-label` it makes a best guess 'oh this must have been what the developer meant' and adds them to the accessibility tree.

The [voiceover guide](https://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/_1131.html) details the controls, obviously it seems you know them but the wording can sometimes be key to understanding behaviours.